# Do I maintain CREATE rights after DROP DATABASE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a user in MySQL with the following privileges:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'certain_db'@'192.168.1.1' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '****'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `certain_db`.* TO 'certain_db'@'192.168.1.1'
```

If I drop this database, do I maintain the right to create it afterwards?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. All information related to user access, privileges, etc is stored in a database named 'mysql'. Information related to database privileges is stored in table 'db'. When you drop a database your privileges over it are not deleted.
So, if you want to create a database with the SAME name later you will be able to.